# Не копируется массив с System.arraycopy

Tags: java, массивы

Нужно сделать копию массива А, чтобы в дальнейшем изменения порядка или значений отдельных элементов в копии не влияли на значения в исходном массиве.

```
    String[][] a=new String[UserData.wordsCount][4]; // wordsCount - размер массива
    System.arraycopy(UserData.wordsArray, 0, a, 0, UserData.wordsCount);        
    System.out.println(a[1][1]);
    UserData.wordsArray[1][1]=null;
    System.out.println(a[1][1]);
```

В результате программа выдает след результат, будто мы просто передали объект другой ссылочной переменной, а не скопировали массив.

```
    'Haus'
    'null'
```

Comment: Насколько понимаю, System.arraycopy не выполняет *deep copy*, просто присваивая соответствующим ячейкам значения необходимые значения. Поэтому да, скорее всего передается ссылка на вложенный массив.

Answer (score 3):

Любой N-мерный массив это одномерный массив, элементами которого являются *ссылки* на массивы размерности N-1.

System.arraycopy копирует как раз эти ссылки, а не само содержимое.

Реализации deep copy (когда копируется содержимое, а не ссылки) насколько я знаю в джаве нету, нужно пилить самому (простым циклом)